# Append URL to filename before uploading to database in PHP

Tags: php, string

I am trying to add a URL to a image file name before uploading it to database. It seems that nothing worked out. Have searched Google and Stackoverflow. I guess I am missing something. Here's my code, please find the comment 'here is the issue'

I have a variable $value which pulls latest ID from database.
All I have to achieve is add path to the variable: "http://example.com/location/something/"

**Desired Output** : the image should be renamed as http://example.com/location/something/1.jpg

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
{    
  $title = $_POST['title'];

$file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

$info = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name']);
$ext = $info['extension']; // get the extension of the file
$folder="uploads/";
function execute_scalar($sql,$def="") {
$rs = mysql_query($sql) or die("bad query");
if (mysql_num_rows($rs)) {
    $r = mysql_fetch_row($rs);
    mysql_free_result($rs);
    return $r[0];
    mysql_free_result($rs);
}
return $def;
}

$value = execute_scalar("select max(ID)+1 from tablename");


$newname = "$value.".$ext; // Here is the issue.
$newname = "http://example.com/location/something/"."$value.".$ext; //did not  work
$newname = "http://example.com/location/something/ $value.".$ext; //did not  work
// even tried assingning url to variable still did not worked

if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$newname))
{
$sql="INSERT INTO   tablename(id,title,image)VALUES('$value','$title','$newname')";
   mysql_query($sql);
 ?>
<script>
alert('successfully uploaded');
    window.location.href='index.php?success';
    </script>
<?php
}
else
{
?>
<script>
alert('error while uploading file');
    window.location.href='index.php?fail';
    </script>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

is it something with URL?

Comment: try echoin'g out each variable before you try concatenating them to make sure they are there, and then try echoing out the `$newname` variable before inserting.   If this works, then try something like this:  `$newname = '$value.'.$ext; `

Comment: You are operating in the _file system_ here. Using _URLs_ in that place doesn’t make any sense.

Comment: The `move_uploaded_file` will probably not work with the resulting file path.

Comment: @CBroe Hi, i am storing the image paths in database and then generating JSON for other apps to access the path and display image.

Comment: @Gumbo if I dont append URL, it works.

Comment: Are you actually getting the file extension?

Comment: You are trying to us a URL _as_ the file name (or part of it) – and that doesn’t really work in most file systems.

Comment: @CBroe any other alternative's. I am not sure.

Comment: did you attempt my first suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your quotes like below:

$newname = "http://example.com/location/something/". $value ."." . $ext;

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not allowed to use **/** (slash) in your file name, because it acts as directory path.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution :

```
$newname =  "http:\\//www.example.com\/location\/something\/\/$value.".$ext;
```

It is working :D